# How can i set delay function in react routing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I set a delay function on React.js? Is there any way to add or remove class in react routing so that page could be transition? Add, remove or toggle class should work every time. Is it possible to add, remove or toggle class on routing with a delay function? or can I use a third party library for that?

```
 import React from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const BasicExample = () => (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
    
          <hr />
    
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
    
    const Home = () => (
      <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </div>
    );
    
    const About = () => (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
    );
    
    const Topics = ({ match }) => (
      <div>
        <h2>Topics</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
    
        <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
        <Route
          exact
          path={match.url}
          render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
        />
      </div>
    );
    
    const Topic = ({ match }) => (
      <div>
        <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
      </div>
    );
    
    export default BasicExample;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/headzoo/8f4c6a5e843ec26abdcad87cd93e3e2e

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * Wraps the React Router Link component and creates a delay after the link is clicked.
 */
export default class DelayLink extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    /**
     * Milliseconds to wait before registering the click.
     */
    delay:        PropTypes.number,
    /**
     * Called after the link is clicked and before the delay timer starts.
     */
    onDelayStart: PropTypes.func,
    /**
     * Called after the delay timer ends.
     */
    onDelayEnd:   PropTypes.func
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    delay:        0,
    onDelayStart: () => {},
    onDelayEnd:   () => {}
  };

  static contextTypes = Link.contextTypes;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.timeout = null;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.timeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Called when the link is clicked
   *
   * @param {Event} e
   */
  handleClick = (e) => {
    const { replace, to, delay, onDelayStart, onDelayEnd } = this.props;
    const { history } = this.context.router;

    onDelayStart(e, to);
    if (e.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (replace) {
        history.replace(to);
      } else {
        history.push(to);
      }
      onDelayEnd(e, to);
    }, delay);
  };

  render() {
    const props = Object.assign({}, this.props);
    delete props.delay;
    delete props.onDelayStart;
    delete props.onDelayEnd;

    return (
      <Link {...props} onClick={this.handleClick} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what does `onDelayStart()` and `onDelayEnd()` do? what should I pass for the props?

Answer (score 9):

I modified the above answer from Paul into a functional component that is more up to date:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link, useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

// Functional link component which delays page navigation
export const DelayLink = props => {
  const { delay, onDelayStart, onDelayEnd, replace, to, ...rest } = props;
  let timeout = null;
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
    };
  }, [timeout]);

  const handleClick = e => {
    // if trying to navigate to current page stop everything
    if (location?.pathname === to) return;

    onDelayStart(e, to);
    if (e.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (replace) {
        history.replace(to);
      } else {
        history.push(to);
      }
      onDelayEnd(e, to);
    }, delay);
  };

  return <Link {...rest} to={to} onClick={handleClick} />;
};

DelayLink.propTypes = {
  // Milliseconds to wait before registering the click.
  delay: PropTypes.number,
  // Called after the link is clicked and before the delay timer starts.
  onDelayStart: PropTypes.func,
  // Called after the delay timer ends.
  onDelayEnd: PropTypes.func,
  // Replace history or not
  replace: PropTypes.bool,
  // Link to go to
  to: PropTypes.string
};

DelayLink.defaultProps = {
  replace: false,
  delay: 0,
  onDelayStart: () => {},
  onDelayEnd: () => {}
};

export default DelayLink;
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/KimPaow/e900d5b9ac4aa483421c6d19f76bb296)

Comment: what does `onDelayStart()` and `onDelayEnd()` do? what should I pass for the props?

Comment: @panjigemilang Those props are functions that will be run before and after the delay timer. So, onDelayStart is run when you click, and onDelayEnd is run when the timer has run out. It's important for timing your animations etc. Check the proptypes for descriptions.

Comment: `let timeout = null` and useEffect with timeout as dependency will not work the same way as in class, timeout will be clear on any re-render, for timout to persist between renders it should be a ref (made with useRef hook)

Answer (score 2):

for me this is the most clear way I use always

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Component() {
const navigate = useNavigate()

// this is a function which returning a promise in the requested time
function wait(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}

// this is the routing function
async function goToPage() {
    // it will navigate to the page 500ms after clicing the div
    await wait(500);
    navigate(`/movie/${whatever}`);
  }

return <div onClick={goToPage}>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently had the same problem I needed to solve. Made this package to help anyone that needs to do the same.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay-react-route-exit

Comment: for me the easiest and best option.. thank you

Comment: @leka74 I couldn't find the Github repository for this package. I wanted to see what you did to achieve this feature with that hook. Let me know if it's uploaded somewhere. Thanks for the package btw! :D

Comment: nevermind, I just downloaded the package and read the file :P It would be cool to have it in a public repo though, really nice feature. Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for React Router 6

Answer (score 0):

I modified the above answer from Kim into a v6 hook (useNavigate) from v5 hook(useHistory).

```
import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
...
...
let navigate = useNavigate();
...
...
timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (replace) {
        navigate(to, { replace: true });
      } else {
        navigate(to);
      }
      onDelayEnd(e, to);
    }, delay);
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/bangdy/55e9de289cdc6ca1b83a2d4206d8503e)