# How to delay the redirect of a React Router Link component for 1 second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, delay

When you click a link, the browser tries to redirect the user ASAP. How can I add a 1 second delay to this process?

I have the following link:

```
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: `pathname`,
      hash: `#hash`,
    }}
    onClick={this.delayRedirect}
  >
```

Here is what my delayRedirect function looks like:

```
  delayRedirect() {
    // not sure what to put here, to delay the redirect by 1 second
  }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you [seen this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840197/how-can-i-set-delay-function-in-react-routing)?

Comment: take a look to [DelayLink.jsx](https://gist.github.com/headzoo/8f4c6a5e843ec26abdcad87cd93e3e2e)

Comment: I'm curious to know, what is the use case?  maybe if you need to delay a route transition you are not on the right track

Comment: I would like to add a one second delay to load an animation after a link is pressed, just for the purpose of aesthetics. @Sagivb.g

Comment: sounds like a job for `TransitionGroup` have you seen the [animated-transitions](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions) section in `react-router` docs?

Comment: Whoa, that looks really interesting. Will check it out, thanks for the links guys!

Comment: @Tholle all that for react to set a simple setTimeOut??????

Comment: Ended up using the DelayLink component, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Home extends Component {

  delayRedirect = event => {
      const { history: { push } } = this.props;
      event.preventDefault();
      setTimeout(()=>push(to), 1000);
    }
  };
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: `pathname`,
      hash: `#hash`,
    }}
    onClick={this.delayRedirect}
  >
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Use history to push new route after a gap of second

Comment: what is `to` inside the `push` ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my function component version, based on @Shishir's answer:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function CustomLink({ to, children }) {
  const history = useHistory();

  function delayAndGo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do something..

    setTimeout(() => history.push(to), 300);
  }

  return (
    <Link to={to} onClick={delayAndGo}>
      {children}
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Comment: 2021  
`const navigate = useNavigate();

    function delayAndGo(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      navigate(to)
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Based on Pedro's answer, here's a way to add the delayAndGo function inside a component like a NavBar:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function NavBar() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function delayAndGo(e, path) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do something..

    setTimeout(() => history.push(path), 300);
  }

  return (
    <Link to="/" onClick={(e) => delayAndGo(e, "/")}>
        Home
    </Link>
    <Link to="/about" onClick={(e) => delayAndGo(e, "/about")}>
        About
    </Link>
    <Link to="/portfolio" onClick={(e) => delayAndGo(e, "/portfolio")}>
        Portfolio
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Note the `to` value of the `Link` elements do not matter in this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Install module

```
npm install p-min-delay
npm i @loadable/component
```

And Import like

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
import pMinDelay from 'p-min-delay'
```